# Get Distinct Document by Max Value of a Field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a requirement where i should query on two fields out of which one is unique field and one is maximum field.
 Here is my sample collection

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId('59537b7fe08062b9ee8dfdf6'),
    "admin": {
        "model": "abc",
        "version": "00",
        "name":"john",
        "age":"30"
    }
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId('59537b7fe08062b9ee8dfdf7'),
    "admin": {
        "model": "abc",
        "version": "01" ,
        "name":"john",
        "age":"30"
    }
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId('59537b7fe08062b9ee8dfdf8'),
    "admin": {
        "model": "def",
        "version": "00" ,
        "name":"cena",
        "age":"30"
    }
}
```

I have two same models with different versions.I want to query for model with maximum version. I tried by simply sorting the version it does not work for me. 
I am expecting output like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('59537b7fe08062b9ee8dfdf7'),
    "admin": {
        "model": "abc",
        "version": "01" ,
        "name":"john",
        "age":"30"
    }
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId('59537b7fe08062b9ee8dfdf8'),
    "admin": {
        "model": "def",
        "version": "00" ,
        "name":"cena",
        "age":"30"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Something like `db.collectionname.aggregate([
    {"$sort": {"admin.version": -1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$admin.model", "max": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }}},
]);`  Also consider changing version to number instead of string

Comment: I get an nested object max with this query . I want my output to be the whole object as it is. Is that possible ?

Comment: You can add stage `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$max" } }` in 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil said, it is $sort, $group, and $replaceRoot, but with correct values in the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "admin.version": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$admin.model" ,
    "admin": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$admin" } }
])
```

Comment: This is not working for me , i get an error as Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$replaceRoot'.

Comment: Upgrade db to v3. 4 or replace root on application layer.